# Javascript KeyUp is not calling the HTML form

Tags: javascript, post, keyup

To calculate Hash value written in another form i am calling a javascript as below

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#form1').keyup(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: 'HashVB.aspx',
                type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    key: $('#key').val(),
                    salt: $('#salt').val(),
                    txnid: $('#txnid').val(),
                    amount: $('#amount').val(),
                    pinfo: $('#pinfo').val(),
                    fname: $('#fname').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
                    udf5: $('#udf5').val()
                }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    if (json['error']) {
                        $('#alertinfo').html('<i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>' + json['error']);
                    }
                    else if (json['success']) {
                        $('#hash').val(json['success']);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
//-->
</script>
```

This same function is working fine in C#. form1 is the id of form element of this html.

Pls give some clue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try use `.keyup()` on `<input>` instead of `<form>` Or change selector to `$("#form1 input").keyup()`

Little example how `#form` selector not works:

```js
$("#form input").keyup(function(e){
    console.log("input selector: " + $(this).val());
});

$("#form1").keyup(function(e){
    console.log("form slector: "+$(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
</form>

<form id="form1">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I had tried "input" already now i tried "#form1.input" even that won't work.

Comment: Try change dot to space. `#form1.input` -> `#form1 input`. You can update your post and add your form html code if this not work?

Comment: I tried still not working. The only thing i have changed in working code is the "selector".It was #payment_form which is id of form element in master form in that project.In my case there is no master page.